# Can I automate Android/iOS native camera using appium, protractor and selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, protractor, appium

I have to automate a Webapp on Android and iOS that is using native camera. Is it possible using protractor, appium und selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

I believe yes you can

Refer the below article :-

http://testingalert.com/automate-android-actions-using-appium/

Below is the java code. You just need to find similar operation in protector nodeJS

```
public static void keyBoardEvent(int eventNumber)

{

 try

 {

  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C adb shell input keyevent " + eventNumber);

  Thread.sleep(3000);

 } catch (Throwable t)

 {

  t.printStackTrace();

 }

}

By passing the eventNumber, we are able to perform desired event.

For Camera Click, Event Number is 27.

Camera Click implementation: -

 public void clickCamera()

{

 Keywords.keyBoardEvent(27);

 System.out.print("Clicked on Camera ");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is it possible to access the using native camera (Android alert) from protractor (Webview)? I don't have any app. I automate the Webapp in Mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

When the camera button is displayed, then you can run the below code:

```js
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input `keyevent` 27");
   Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unable to trigger the camera.

Comment: Enclose code within triple quotes. This will preserve new lines and indentation which will make the code much easier to look at

Comment: Is this actually a question?

Answer (score -1):

After clicking on application element which leads you to the options camera or gallery

```java
driver.findElement(
    By.xpath(
        "//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.TextView[@text='Camera']"
    )).click();
```

it will work for all the devices from marshmallow to pie

Then

```java
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input `keyevent` 'KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN'");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

or

```java
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input `keyevent` 27");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

it will click the camera shutter button

Then you have to select the option done to proceed to use these `xpath` for respective devices

```java
xpath = "//android.widget.ImageButton[@id='shutter_button']"; //(for google camera)

id = "okay"; //(samsung devices)

id = "com.android.camera2:id/done_button"; //(google pixel camera)
```

If there is no locator presents for that element then use this

```java
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input `keyevent` 'KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP'");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
control will be back into your native application
```